# Let TypeScript compiler know that the data is present in React-Query

Tags: react-query

React-Query generally returns some query states such as `isLoading`, `isError`. The library guarantees that these booleans are stable. This means we can be sure that the data is present if e. g. check for the `onSuccess` boolean. However, this - of course - isn't enough for the TS compiler. Even after the check, it assumes that the data can be `undefined`. What's the best way to let the TS compiler know that the data is present?

Here's an example from the docs:

```
function Todos() {
   const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
 
   if (isLoading) {
     return <span>Loading...</span>
   }
 
   if (isError) {
     return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
   }
 
   // --> The data is now sure to exist

   return (
     <ul>
       {data.map(todo => ( // --> this will not work with the TS compiler.
         <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   )
 }
```

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm having the same issue where it should work but the TS compiler is still complaining.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

react-query added discriminated unions in v3, so this generally works. You can discriminate by the `status` field as well as the derived boolean flags. However, there are two things that you need to keep in mind:

1. discriminated unions do not work if you destruct. This has nothing to do with react-query, but with TypeScript. If you take a field "out" of an object with destructuring, it can no longer discriminate that object.
2. react-query has an additional state: `isIdle` (or `status === 'idle'`), which will be true if the query is disabled via `enabled: false`.

Keeping these two things in mind, this should work:

```
function Todos() {
   const queryInfo = useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
 
   if (queryInfo.isLoading || queryInfo.isIdle) {
     return <span>Loading...</span>
   }
 
   if (queryInfo.isError) {
     return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
   }
 
   // --> The data is now sure to exist

   return (
     <ul>
       {queryInfo.data.map(todo => ( // --> TS is happy now
         <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   )
 }
```

of course, you can also just check for `isSuccess` or `status === 'success'` to narrow the type.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to load data once e.g. on the application start, I personally like to use "Gate" component. The role of the gate is to stop futher rendering as long as data is not loaded yet. When data is finally loaded I use context&customHook to read my initial data. At this point Im sure that my data will not be undefined. You can check a PoC [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x65k5x?file=index.tsx)